# Error on using REPLACE character manipulation function on query SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

it gives me an error when I am using this key but when I use LENGTH, it works fine. I hope it is allowed on android sqlite coz it's the best way for this:

I am just trying to remove the spaces after words that will be selected from Database.

```
public ArrayList<String> getCorrectList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLACE(Level_1, ' ', '') FROM " + TABLE, null);

        ArrayList<String> resultsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    do {
                        String levelData = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("Level_1"));

            resultsList.add("" + c.getColumnIndex("Level_1"));

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            Log.e("Database", "Cannot get List (" + e + ")");

        }

        Log.d("array", "List: " + resultsList);

        Collections.shuffle(resultsList);

        return resultsList;
    }
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in SQLite3 shell:

```
e$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.14.1 2012-10-04 19:37:12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t(a,b,c);
sqlite> select replace(a,' ', '') from t;
```

`REPLACE` is both a function and a command in SQLite3.  Perhaps `db.rawQuery` is parsing the query and getting confused by `REPLACE`. Try this:

```
db.rawQuery("select rtrim(replace(Level_1, ' ', '')) FROM " + TABLE, null);
```